# Numerical logaritmic derivative

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods

I`m interesting in numerical evaluation of logaritmic derivative (gradient) of some function $f(x)>0, x\subset\mathbb{R}^3$, i.e. $\frac{d\log f(x)}{d x}$. My $f(x)$ is relatively smooth (2nd derivatives exist and likely higher too) and I have its values approximated on a regular mesh. What is better from numerical point of view, compute logarithm of $f(x)$ and find the derivative of this new function $g(x)\equiv\log f(x)$ or to compute derivative of $f(x)$ and just divide the result by $f(x)$? Or is there a better option?

If I did not have values of $f(x)$ on a regular mesh, but can evaluate $f(x)$ wherever I want, would that make any difference?

If $f(x)\propto G_{\sigma}(x)$*$\exp{(-\phi/2\nu)}$, where $G_{\sigma}(x)$ is a gaussian field, $\phi(x)>0$ is a potential $(\nabla\times\phi=0)$, $\nu>0$ and * denotes convolution, would that make any difference?

Comment: If $x \gg 1$ then $f(x) \sim e^{\pm x}$ may overflow/underflow and differentiating $f(x)$ numerically is not a good idea. It's better to differentiate the logarithm instead.

Comment: But if $f(x)\ll1$ then I would get huge errors when subtracting two logarithms near $0$...

Comment: What about decidng which scheme use based on value of $f(x)$? Like when $f(x)<\epsilon_D\sim0.5$ use differentiating $f(x)$, otherwis the logarithm?

Comment: when $f(x) \ll 1$ the denominator in $\frac{f(x+h) - f(x-h)}{2h f(x)}$ blows up the round-off error of the numerator, while the logarithms stay around $\log x > -300$ for double precision. A simple numerical experiment shows slightly better performance of $\frac{\log f(x+h) - \log f(x-h)}{2h}$ for $f(x) = e^{-\frac{1}{3} (\cos (\pi  x)-x)^2}$ on $x \in [-5, 5]$